# Android - Create a module(library) manually

Tags: java, android, module

Iam using [AndroidIde](https://androidide.com/) to create my applications I need to create a library but there is no way to create a module, how can I create a module manually.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639227/3169238) should solve your question

Comment: @SergeiKozelko I said create not add.